# Selecting the oldest updated set of entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table `my_entry`:

```
Id int(11) AI PK
InternalId varchar(30)
UpdatedDate datetime
IsDeleted bit(1)
```

And I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    `Id`, `InternalId`
FROM
    `my_entry`
WHERE
   (`IsDeleted` = FALSE)
        AND ((`UpdatedDate` IS NULL
        OR DATE(`UpdatedDate`) != DATE(STR_TO_DATE('17/10/2019', '%d/%m/%Y'))))
ORDER BY `x`.`UpdatedDate`
Limit 200;
```

The table has around 3M records, I have a program running that executes the above query and returns 200 entries from the table that weren't updated today, the program then changes those 200 entries and updates them again setting the `UpdatedDate` to today's date, on the next execution those 200 entries will be ignored, and new 200 entries will get selected, this keeps running until all the entries in the table are selected and updated for today.
This way I can ensure that all the entries are updated at least once every day.

This works perfectly fine, for the very first thousands of entries, the select query executes in a couple of milliseconds, but as soon as more entries are updated and have today's date in the `UpdatedDate` the query keeps slowing down, reaching execution times up to 20 seconds.

I'm wondering if I can do something to optimize the query, or if there is a better approach to take without using the UpdatedDate.
I was thinking of using the `Id` and paginating the entries, but I'm afraid this way I might miss some of them.

What I already tried:

- Adding indexes to both the UpdatedDate and IsDeleted.
- Changing the `UpdatedDate` type from `datetime` to `date`.

**Edit:**

MySql version: 5.6.45

The table in hand:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_entry` (
   `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `InternalId` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   `UpdatedDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `IsDeleted` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `InternalId` (`InternalId`),
   KEY `UpdatedDate` (`UpdatedDate`),
   KEY `entry_isdeleted_index` (`IsDeleted`) USING BTREE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8204626 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

The output of the EXPLAIN query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+------+---------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  |            possible_keys            |     key     | key_len | ref  | rows |     Extra     |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+------+---------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | x     | index | "UpdatedDate entry_isdeleted_index" | UpdatedDate |       4 | NULL |  400 | "Using where" |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+------+---------------+
```

Example of data in the table:

```
+------------+--------+---------------------+-----------+
| InternalId |   Id   |     UpdatedDate     | IsDeleted |
+------------+--------+---------------------+-----------+
|  328044773 | 552990 | 2019-10-17 10:11:29 |         0 |
|  330082707 | 552989 | 2019-10-17 10:11:29 |         0 |
|  329701688 | 552988 | 2019-10-17 10:11:29 |         0 |
|  329954358 | 552987 | 2019-10-16 10:11:29 |         0 |
|  964227577 | 552986 | 2019-10-16 12:33:29 |         0 |
|  329794593 | 552985 | 2019-10-16 12:33:29 |         0 |
|  400015773 | 552984 | 2019-10-16 12:33:29 |         0 |
|  330674329 | 552983 | 2019-10-16 12:33:29 |         0 |
+------------+--------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Example expected output of the query:

```
+------------+--------+
| InternalId |   Id   |
+------------+--------+
|  329954358 | 552987 |
|  964227577 | 552986 |
|  329794593 | 552985 |
|  400015773 | 552984 |
|  330674329 | 552983 |
+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Note: Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is pretty much meaningless as SQL is defined to be **orderless** in the tables or resultsets..

Comment: *"I'm wondering if I can do something to optimize the query"* Questions about performance should ideally  at minimal include MySQL version -> `SELECT VERSION()` (as the optimizer is (very) different between major MySQL versions), a `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` foreach table involved in the question.. A `EXPLAIN query` output..

Comment: ... . And maybe example data and expected results when a query rewrite might be needed -> [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Index is not used if you use function in where condition

Comment: @RaymondNijland You are right, I actually had the order by but forgot to include it in the above query, I have also included all the missing details that you have mentioned, please let me know if I forgot anything.

Comment: ... still that `ORDER BY` also can be meaningless where `UpdatedDate` have equal values in the records..  Pagination / batching processing of any kind requires always a deterministic order by.. Meaning the safe method is to also atleast include one column in the `ORDER BY` which you know for sure has unique values in this case the `id` or `InternalId` meaning -> `ORDER BY UpdatedDate, id ASC/DESC`

Comment: *"Index is not used if you use function in where condition "* @James is right here offcource, `DATE(UpdatedDate) != DATE(STR_TO_DATE('17/10/2019', '%d/%m/%Y'))` can be made *"sargable"* with  `UpdatedDate < '2019-10-17' OR UpdatedDate > '2019-10-17'` ...  *"sargable"* is a term for factoring out functions at the left side of a operator to make a RDMS use indexes.. See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wgW8pBAsTaSPT6SJhbzJGq/4) .. Note: MySQL choose the full table scan in the demo  when you run EXPLAIN because that is cheapest method on this low number of records..

Comment: .. Anyhow more things needs to happen most likey as it is not logical to index `IsDeleted` as it only can contain two values the RDMS which choose a table scan more likely then a index when filtering with `WHERE isdeleted = 0` on this column..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, simplify the date arithmetic.  Then take the following approach:

- Take NULL values in one subquery
- Take rows on the date in another
- Then order and select the results

Start by writing the query as:

```
SELECT Id, InternalId
FROM ((SELECT Id, InternalId, 2 as priority
       FROM my_entry
       WHERE NOT IsDeleted AND UpdatedDate IS NULL
       LIMIT 200
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT Id, InternalId, 1 as priority
       FROM my_entry
       WHERE NOT IsDeleted AND UpdatedDate <> '2019-10-17'
       LIMIT 200
      )
     ) t
ORDER BY priority
LIMIT 200;
```

The index that you want is either `(updateddate, isdeleted)` or `(isdeleted, updateddate)`.  You can add `id` and `internalid`.

The idea is to select at most 200 rows from the two subqueries *without sorting*.  Then the outer query is sorting at most 400 rows -- and that should not take multiple seconds.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . I don't think so.  The deleted seems to apply to both conditions.

Comment: It seems that adding the composite index (updateddate, isdeleted) helps tremendously, Removing the date() function from the query helps as well.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think the reason the query is returning wrong results is because of the condition UpdatedDate = '2019-10-17' it should be UpdatedDate != '2019-10-17'

Comment: yes that is indeed the case.. @Ayoub_B i believe i should not make comments anymore when low on caffeine it seams ...  Anyhow keep in mind that this query could possible give other results on every query run as the inner select are not using a `ORDER BY` with the `LIMIT` Gordon didn't say that explicit